# Weird FOR ORDINALITY column behavior for json_table query with nested path in Oracle 12.1

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql

I have a JSON text in a clob:

```
[
  {
    "debitOverturn": "939.34",
    "table": [
      {
        "debit": "",
        "credit": "939.34"
      },
      {
        "debit": "939.34",
        "credit": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "debitOverturn": "939.34",
    "table": [
      {
        "debit": "",
        "credit": "939.34"
      },
      {
        "debit": "939.34",
        "credit": ""
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

trying to query it on oracle 12.1:

```
SELECT jt.u_lvl,
       jt.debitOverturn,
       jt.l_lvl,
       jt.debit,
       jt.credit
 FROM test1 s,
     JSON_TABLE (s.json_data,'$[*]' COLUMNS (
        u_lvl FOR ORDINALITY,
        debitOverturn VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.debitOverturn',
        NESTED PATH '$.table[*]'
            COLUMNS (
                l_lvl FOR ORDINALITY,
                debit VARCHAR2(38) PATH '$.debit',
                credit VARCHAR2(38) PATH '$.credit'))) AS jt
   WHERE s.id = 1;
```

and see some weird result in u_lvl column:

```
U_LVL   DEBITOVERTURN   L_LVL   DEBIT   CREDIT
1   939.34  1   (null)  939.34
2   939.34  2   939.34  (null)
3   939.34  1   (null)  939.34
4   939.34  2   939.34  (null)
```

It looks like FOR ORDINALITY column counts all rows in the query instead of rows at its level. So I tried to rerun task at my home VM server with Oracle 12.2 and got different (and much more reliable) result:

```
U_LVL   DEBITOVERTURN   L_LVL   DEBIT   CREDIT
1   939.34  1   (null)  939.34
1   939.34  2   939.34  (null)
2   939.34  1   (null)  939.34
2   939.34  2   939.34  (null)
```

Then I tried to run the same query at Oracle Livesql server (livesql.oracle.com) and got another result:

```
U_LVL   DEBITOVERTURN   L_LVL   DEBIT   CREDIT
1   939.34  1   (null)  939.34
1   939.34  2   939.34  (null)
1   939.34  1   (null)  939.34
1   939.34  2   939.34  (null)
```

Is that an Oracle bug? Or the difference between major DB releases? Is FOR ORDINALITY behaviour can be adjusted in some deep DB settings?

Comment: Have a look at [MoS Doc ID 2301973.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2301973.1). I see the same result on livesql (which is 12.2.0.1) as you do on your own 12.2 though.

Comment: I cannot replicate your results on [livesql.oracle.com](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/f5dbnatdytpug7j81pin1o7b4). It appears to give the same output as your Oracle 12.2 results.

Comment: Thanx, Alex, looks like this patch is a solution! As for livesql - this post with all the query results was originally written a couple of weeks ago on another site but there were no answers there and reposted it here (and got an answer in a first day, woohoo). So then query result on livesql was exactly like I described above, but after I tried it right now, is shows me the same result as 12.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in the `JSON_TABLE` function in 12.1. If you can't upgrade to 12.2 a patch is available, but you'll have to have a support account to get it.

Further details are on the Oracle support site, in [Doc ID 2301973.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2301973.1).